# How does forem compare to essem?

Tags: classical-latin, word-comparison, conjugation, esse

The verb *esse* has two sets of imperfect conjunctive forms: *essem, esses, esset…* and *forem, fores, foret…*

What is the difference between these two, in meaning and in use?
Are there cases where only *essem* is valid, or ones where only *forem* is?
When both are valid, is there a difference in meaning?
Unfortunately my grammar does not discuss *forem* at all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For my answer, I will use material from a 1931 article written to address this very issue: "The Use of Forem and Essem" by Winnie D. Lawrence, [available on JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/282971).

Abstract:

> While *essem* was always a good literary word, *forem*, after Plautus, gave evidence of decline in this respect. In later writers, especially in Sallust and Tacitus, it was an affected archaism, but in the poets, metrical convenience also was often the deciding factor in its use. The etymology of *forem* suggests a future meaning and those who employ it most frequently have a strong feeling for this quality. Syntactically, *forem* is met most often in conditional sentences, being employed in this way in 42% of its occurrences, while *essem* is so used in only 15%.

Here are some general points sprinkled with the findings of Lawrence's study, which includes a fairly rigorous statistical analysis:

### *forem* has a future tendency

*forem* comes from the PIE root "BHEU", *essem* from "ES." "BHEU" survives in other forms like fu-, fore, and the -ba- and -bo- endings of the imperfect and future (and also English's *be*!). A rough equivalent "future subjunctive" survives in Spanish (*fuere*) and Portuguese (*for*). This future force was recognized by Roman authors, even though it can also be granted to *essem*:

Servius, commenting on the *Aeneid*, remarks with surprise when Vergil uses *forem* without any future kind of meaning:

> modo praeteritum significat tempus, quod rarum est, **saepius enim futurum significat**. (Servius on *Aen.* III, 417)

Some examples:

> Ilio tria fuisse audivi fata quae illi forent exitio. (Pl. *Bacch.* 953)

Sallust is especially prone to this kind of usage, using *forem* 33 times with a future sense (e.g. as a substitute for *ero* in indirect discourse) and *essem* only once. One quote in particular even juxtaposes *essem* and *fores* with these two different senses:

> At Catilina ex itinere...litteras mittit: se...in exitium proficisci, non quo sibi tanti sceleris **conscius esset**, sed uti res public **quieta foret**... (Sal. *Cat.* 34, 2)

Note that this is only a *tendency* with multiple exceptions. However, as Lawrence remarks, "those who use *forem* most often have a strong feeling for its future quality."

### *forem* is more archaic and colloquial

Earlier writers, such as Plautus, use *forem* comparatively frequently (about 25% of the time). Lucretius uses *forem* more often than *essem*.

Later, more formal writers tend to shy away from heavy usage of *forem*. The most prominent example of this is Vergil, who does not use *forem* at all in the *Eclogues* or *Georgics* and uses it only 15 times in the *Aeneid* (we will see why in the next section).

Sallust used the word heavily, but was also often accused of over-employing archaisms.

### *forem* is great for meter

In my opinion, the most cogent conclusion of Lawrence's study is that *forem* is chosen by poets not for any difference of meaning but because of *metrical expediency*. *Forem* is ideal for metrical schemes ending in an iamb, for instance. Likewise, *forem* is often placed after words ending in a vowel which would cause an elision. Some striking figures:

- Terence uses *forem* 8 times: 7 are at the end of a line requiring an iamb, and 1 is after a vowel that would otherwise be elided.
- Lucretius: 21 out of 27 cases avoid elision
- Catullus: 7 out 9 avoid elision: in *all 9* cases using *essem* would violate the meter
- Notably, Vergil, who is known for his elision, uses *essem* much more often.

### *forem* fits better with certain constructions

Besides the previous cases, there is one particularly one construction in which *forem* predominates: **conditionals**. This is very likely a matter of sound, especially for poets, since *si essem* is unpleasant.

- Half of Terence's *forem*'s are in conditionals
- Quintilian, Seneca Philosophus, and Pliny--who otherwise use *forem* very rarely--use *forem* at a much higher percentage in conditionals
- Tacitus also provides numerous examples, e.g. "Si in Britannia foret" (Ag. 40), "si mali forent" (Hist 1.49), "si vera forent" (Ann 2.8)

This is likely a question of sound and feel, since a sensitive prose or poetry writer will carefully balance his usage of *s*'s. This seems to explain, for instance, some of the few times when Vergil opts for *forem*.

At the end of the day, though, we must always appeal to that invisible, inexplicable "choice" an author makes between two roughly equivalent words: the two words evidently have different "feels", but I would hesitate to formulate any kind of *rules* that apply to all particular cases.